# Why do I get the same result with "ga:users" and "ga:newUsers"?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the google analytics API to count the number of users (ga:users) in a month after applying a filter on a custom variable, and I get the same number as the number of new users (ga:newUsers) with the same filter.

However, if I go on the webUI, I don't get the same numbers. ga:newUsers is correct in both the API and the webUI, but ga:users is wrong in the API.

Is this a bug?

Comment: For the API, are you querying per daily basis ? In the UI do you compare your numbers from the graph or the Overview ?

Comment: Can you show your code and the output?

Comment: @Igneel64: I am not querying on a daily basis. In the UI, I select a segment which is a filter on a custom variable. With that segment applied, I go to the Audience > Overview > Users, and I see 1000 (fake number just sake of explanation). Then, I go to Audience > Custom with the same segment applied and I see 500 in the table under the column "New Users". If I then go to the query explorer, and I query the API asking for the metric "ga:users" with the same filter as the segment above, I get 500 (and it should be 1000). If I select "ga:newUsers", I also get 500.

Comment: @diskesh: The code is in Python and it looks like `service.data().ga().get('ids': XXX, 'start_date': '2017-02-01', 'end-date': '2017-02-28', 'metrics': 'ga:users', 'filters': 'ga:customVarValue2==XXX').execute()`. This gives me the **same value** as the "New Users" column in the Custom > Audience section in the webUI when I apply a segment on the same custom variable (see my comment above).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the segment on the webUI applies the filter on **sessions**, whereas I don't specify it's for sessions on the python code above (or in the query explorer). Is that what's happening?

Comment: Try querying the ga:sessions metric together with ga:users. GA API is misbehaving some times